# Receiving 403 (forbidden) from CLU whenever initiate the bot composer from custom adapter like (wechat, twiliio)

Tags: bots, twilio, botframework, adapter, .net-7.0

I'm writing a custom adapter of twilio for whatsapp in .net.
When I try to send a message from twilio adapter to bot composer it gives me 403(forbidden) from CLU in response of that activity but without adapter it is working fine

I'm new in bot composer.Any direction would be appreciated.

I'm using CLU as recognizer

```
{
  "$kind": "Microsoft.CluRecognizer",
  "projectName": "${settings.clu.projectName}",
  "endpoint": "${settings.clu.endpoint}",
  "endpointKey": "${settings.clu.endpointKey}",
  "deploymentName": "${settings.clu.deploymentName}"
}
```

Below is the error:

"StackTrace": "   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Components.Recognizers.CLURecognizer.CluRecognizerOptions.GetCluResponseAsync(String utterance, HttpClient httpClient, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Components.Recognizers.CLURecognizer.CluRecognizerOptions.RecognizeAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, String utterance, HttpClient httpClient, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Components.Recognizers.CLURecognizer.CluRecognizerOptions.RecognizeInternalAsync(DialogContext dialogContext, Activity activity, HttpClient httpClient, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Components.Recognizers.CLURecognizer.CLU.CluMainRecognizer.RecognizeInternalAsync(DialogContext dialogContext, Activity activity, CluRecognizerOptionsBase predictionOptions, Dictionary`2 telemetryProperties, Dictionary`2 telemetryMetrics, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Components.Recognizers.CLURecognizer.CLU.CluMainRecognizer.RecognizeAsync(DialogContext dialogContext, Activity activity, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Components.Recognizers.CluAdaptiveRecognizer.RecognizeAsync(DialogContext dialogContext, Activity activity, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Dictionary`2 telemetryProperties, Dictionary`2 telemetryMetrics)\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Recognizers.RecognizerSet.RecognizeAsync(DialogContext dialogContext, Activity activity, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Dictionary`2 telemetryProperties, Dictionary`2 telemetryMetrics)\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.AdaptiveDialog.OnRecognizeAsync(ActionContext actionContext, Activity activity, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.AdaptiveDialog.ProcessEventAsync(ActionContext actionContext, DialogEvent dialogEvent, Boolean preBubble, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.AdaptiveDialog.ProcessEventAsync(ActionContext actionContext, DialogEvent dialogEvent, Boolean preBubble, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.AdaptiveDialog.ProcessEventAsync(ActionContext actionContext, DialogEvent dialogEvent, Boolean preBubble, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.AdaptiveDialog.OnPreBubbleEventAsync(DialogContext dc, DialogEvent dialogEvent, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Dialog.OnDialogEventAsync(DialogContext dc, DialogEvent e, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContainer.OnDialogEventAsync(DialogContext dc, DialogEvent e, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.AdaptiveDialog.BeginDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(String dialogId, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogExtensions.InnerRunAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, String dialogId, DialogContext dialogContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogExtensions.InternalRunAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, String dialogId, DialogContext dialogContext, DialogStateManagerConfiguration stateConfiguration, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"